# JavaScript to dynamically make a SVG wont work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

so i wrote this simple script that reads values from input and uses them to build a bar graph dynamically, but for some reason the script isnt working' any ideas?

```
 <figure id="fg1">
     <input type="hidden" id="myText" value ="10 20 30 15 40 5" />
     <figcaption ><br/>Activity Graph </figcaption >

  </figure>
<script>
    var str = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var res = str.split(" ");
    var s = "<svg id="svg1">";
 for (i=0 ; i < res.length; i++) {
    var cx = i*20;
   s+="<rect class="hist" " +"x=""+cx+"+"width="20""+"height=""+res[i]*20+" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />";

}
s+="</svg>";
$('s').appendTo("#fg1");

</script>
```

Comment: _' isnt working'_ is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote the variable. That makes it a string, so it's selecting a `<s>` tag in the DOM.

```
$(s).appendTo("#fg1");
```

Comment: thaks for the reply, i changed it but it just isnt doing any thing. i tried a simple code as below but still nothing....

Comment: <figure id="fg1">
     <input type="hidden" id="myText" value ="10 20 30 15 40 5" />
     <figcaption ><br/>Activity Graph </figcaption >

  </figure>

<script>
  var test ="<svg width="400" height="110"><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>";
  $(test).appendTo("#fg1");
</script>

Answer (score 1):

When you create SVG elements dynamically you should use the `document.createElementNS(namespaceUri, elementName)` method since they're not HTML tags.

E.g. to create a `<rect>` node you should use:

```
var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ,"rect");
```

Then you can append it to your svg with `svg.appendChild(el)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use normal jQuery to create SVG elements.  jQuery creates elements in the default (HTML) namespace.  SVG elements are required to be in the SVG namespace.  Try using the jQuery.SVG plugin instead.

Or create the elements individually yourself using `createElementNS()` as Andreas suggested.